# How to sort a range in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple range to sort.

The code below was written by the Macro Recorder, it works.

I will be using this countless of times in a LOT of other ranges. Is this the correct way, or is there a better shorter more streamlined way?

```
Sub test6()

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Weekly Sorted").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Weekly Sorted").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "AK6:AK12"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Weekly Sorted").Sort
        .SetRange Range("AG6:AK12")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The only thing you can really do it make a subroutine out of it and pass the sub a string equal to the range (assuming it's always on the same sheet)  - but it wont make it any faster, it will just make it easier to maintain.

Comment: I use the sorting which was there in Excel 2003. Change as applicable. `ws.Columns("A:AE").Sort Key1:=ws.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess,         OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom,         DataOption1:=xlSortNormal`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably be better served using the .sort method.

```
Sub SortRange()

  Dim MyRange As Range

  Set MyRange = Sheets("Weekly Sorted").Range("AK6:AK12")

  With MyRange
    .Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
  End With

End Sub
```

The above example sorts the entire range based on values in the 1st column. Hope this helps.

Edit:

Per comments, the below will allow you to easily write multiple lines to sort multiple tables. Use the SortRanges sub to add multiple tables and remember not to include headers in your sort range.

```
Private Sub SortRanges()

  'Sort per your example address
  SortMyRange Sheets("Weekly Sorted").Range("AG6:AK12")

  'Other examples below

  'Sorts a range on a sheet named "Monthly Sorted", in descending order based on values in the 4th column of the specified range
  SortMyRange Sheets("Monthly Sorted").Range("A2:D12"), 4, xlDescending

  'Sorts a range on a sheet named "Daily Sorted", in ascending order based on values in the 2nd column of the specified range
  SortMyRange Sheets("Daily Sorted").Range("AG6:AK12"), 2, xlAscending

End Sub

Public Sub SortMyRange(ByRef RangeToSort As Range, Optional ByVal SortByColumn As Long = 1, _
  Optional ByVal SortOrder As XlSortOrder = xlAscending)

  With RangeToSort
    .Sort Key1:=.Columns(SortByColumn), Order1:=SortOrder, Header:=xlNo
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great thank you, what if I have more ranges to sort? can I incorporate more ranges to the above code? like adding the range A6:A12 and B6:B12 as well, or maybe I can add multiple MyRange= lines? like MyRange2=  and MyRange3=  and so on?

Comment: I'll adjust the answer to include multiple ranges. :-)

Comment: Wow that is just beautiful, thank you so much Judge

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about it.

1. **Old Fashioned way** [Sort Method -Excel 2003](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa213557(v%3Doffice.11))

Use this code

```
ws.Columns("A:AE").Sort Key1:=ws.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

2. **New Way**

Convert your code in a sub as shown below (**Untested**) and pass the worksheet/range to it as @braX suggested

```
Sub SortRange(ws As Worksheet, rng As Range)
    With ws
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        With .Sort
            .SetRange rng
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```